# Find whether timezone name is deprecated in pytz

Tags: python, pytz

In order to make my API return proper timezone strings (with proper, I mean any that are not marked "deprecated" in the latest [specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones); so that the consumer of the API has some guarantee on what the valid values are), I would like to check in `pytz` whether a zone-name is deprecated (and even better: which are canonical, and which are aliases).

`pytz` has a `common_timezones` fields, which, according to the [documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net), "doesn’t contain deprecated zones or historical zones, except for a few I’ve deemed in common usage, such as US/Eastern". So it feels this almost does the job, however not quite yet; because indeed "US/Eastern" is deprecated officially.

I could obviously now manually get a list of non-deprecated zones, or keep a list of zones that `pytz` considers `common_timezones`, but are actually deprecated (note the "such as" in the documentation description above), however this would mean I should update this list manually every time I update pytz.

So the question, is there a way to find out in pytz if a zone(name) is deprecated (or alias / canonical)?